# After redirect from setTimeout, Chrome & Edge back button doesn't work well

Tags: javascript, settimeout

When redirecting to another page using `setTimeout()` either by setting `window.location.href` or by clicking an anchor `object` from code, Chrome and Edge back button don't redirect back to my page, but to the page before that.
This works well in Firefox and also in chrome when I call `history.back()` from the console.

I used this test page to reproduce the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta chrset="UTF 8">
</head>
<body>
    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">Link</a>
    <button type="button">Button</button>
    <script>
        setTimeout(() => document.querySelector('a').click(), 3000);

        document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click',
            () => document.querySelector('a').click());
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If I click the button the chrome's back button works fine, but if I let the `setTimeout` do the redirect the problem occurs.

It's better to try it on a newly opened tab.

Comment: It's either a Chrome *feature* or *bug* - wait until next release to find out (so, it behaves the same in v112 and v113 - probably a *feature*)

Answer (score 2):

From my experience and understanding, this issue may be related to how Chrome and Edge handle page caching and history navigation. When you use `setTimeout` to redirect to a new page, the browser may cache the previous page in memory, which can interfere with the behavior of the back button.

To solve this issue, you can try using the `location.replace` method instead of `window.location.href` to perform the redirect. The `replace` method updates the current entry in the browser’s history with the new URL, instead of creating a new entry. This can help ensure that the back button works as expected when navigating back to the previous page.

I've provided a code snippet to address your issue that uses `location.replace`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset=“UTF-8”>
</head>
<body>
    <a href=“https://stackoverflow.com/”>Link</a>
    <button type=“button”>Button</button>
    <script>
        setTimeout(() => location.replace(‘https://stackoverflow.com/’), 3000);

        document.querySelector(‘button’).addEventListener(‘click’,
            () => location.replace(’https://stackoverflow.com/'));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In this version, the `setTimeout` and button click event handlers use `location.replace` instead of `document.querySelector(‘a’).click()` or `window.location.href` to redirect to the new page.

Note that using `location.replace` instead of `window.location.href` has some implications for your application’s behavior. Specifically, using `replace` removes the previous entry from the browser’s history, so the user won’t be able to navigate back to the previous page using the back button. If this is not a concern for your application, using `replace` may be a viable solution to the back button issue you’re experiencing in Chrome and Edge.

Try it out, if it doesn't' work  possible solution to this issue is to use the `history.pushState` method to modify the browser’s history stack when performing the redirect.
The `pushState` method adds a new entry to the browser’s history stack, which allows the back button to work as expected when navigating back to the previous page.

```
 <script>
        setTimeout(() => {
            history.pushState(null, null, 'https://stackoverflow.com/');
            window.location.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com/';
        }, 3000);

        document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
            history.pushState(null, null, 'https://stackoverflow.com/');
            window.location.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com/';
        });
    </script>
```

Here is the MDN doc for `pushState` [History: pushState() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState)

Comment: The first solution is not what i asked for. i want the back button to be able to go back to the previous pages and not eliminate the history. the second solution doesn't solve the problem. back button still doesn't work right. also history.pushState() fails when redirecting to a different domain.

Answer (score 1):

I think its something with the browser caching mechanism. Have you tried to disable the caching?

```html
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
```

Comment: Tried you solution and it didn't work